# Solving a differential equation with second member defined by parts

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving this differential equation. I get confused in the integrations and on how to find the constants.

$$ u''(x) = f(x) =\begin{cases} -1 \: \text{if } 0.4<x<0.6 \\ 0 \: \text{if } x \notin  [0.4,0.6]  \end{cases}  $$ for $x \in [0,1]$
and $u(0) =-1$, $u(1)=1$.

I tried to integrate the two parts but I end up with too many unknowns.

I would like to have your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You used the tag partial-differential-equations. This looks like an  ordinary differential equation to me. That is, we are looking for a function of one variable.

Comment: @Gonçalo  thanks for your answer but when I write the system, I can't find any solution.

Comment: @Gonçalo I used wolfram alpha, and it tells me that there are no solutions.   https://i.imgur.com/7CkHlrf.png . I took $u(0)=u(1)=0$ to simplify the calculations

Comment: @Gonçalo https://i.imgur.com/IyXAROf.png There is still no solution :(